# How can I center images in flex display?

Tags: html, css, image

So I am a new developer who is kind-of in-training. I have been working on a website for a little while now as practice, but my images won't center despite everything I've tried. The code I am running is also the excact same as the tutorial I was watching, and that guys images lined up perfectly. I will upload an image of my website.

This is my website preview. The three images are the un-centered ones.

[image: This is my website preview, the three images are the un-centered ones.]

```css
.features {
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    color: grey;
}


.features figure {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
}

.features figure img {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
    <section class="features">
        
        <figure>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"alt="E Girl Skin">
            <figcaption>Skin Uno Mununo</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Mario Skin">
            <figcaption>Skin Dosos</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="E Boy Skin">
            <figcaption>Skin Treses</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
```

Comment: Looks to me like your images _are_ centered. Maybe revise to describe better what you want to accomplish. Also, why are your images sized twice as big as their figure containers?

Comment: ...They aren't centered... As you can see, the margin between the side of the steering wheel and the website side is larger than that of the right image and the website side.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: url("Grey-Gradient-Background.jpg");
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
header {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 0px;
    background-image: url("Blue-Bg-Header.jpeg");
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

footer {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: white;
    margin: 0px, 0px, 0px, 0px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.features {
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    color: grey;
}

.features figure {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
}

.features figure{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.figImg{object-fit: contain;width: 200px;border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;}

header .logo a {
    /* background: url("Novak_Skinz-Removebg-crop.png"); */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 160px;
    /* text-indent: -99999999px; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    /* color:black; */
    color: white;
  }
  
  /* visited link */
  a:visited {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
  
  /* mouse over link */
  a:hover {
    color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
  }
  
  /* selected link */
  a:active {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }

  a {
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  a {
      font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="styles.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="E:\Microsoft VS Code-Folder\new.css"> 
</head>

    <header>
        <nav>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About Me.html">About Me</a></li>
                <li class="logo"><a href="index.html">Novakron Logo</a></li>
                <li><a href="Pricing.html">Pricing</a></li> 
                <li><a href="Contact Me.html">Contact Me</a></li>
             </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </header>   
    <section class="features">
        
        <figure>
            <img src="#" alt="E Girl Skin" class="figImg">
            <figcaption>Skin Uno Mununo</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="3" alt="Mario Skin"  class="figImg">
            <figcaption>Skin Dosos</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="3" alt="E Boy Skin" class="figImg">
            <figcaption>Skin Treses</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>

<footer>
Contact me @NovakSkinz@gmail.com OR 555-999-3333
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

In .features, add:

```
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

That should do it! LMK ("let me know") otherwise.

Comment: Lmk is common text language in English for "let me know," and is frequently seen in internet forums! And I can format the `code` if you'd like, I just assumed the 2 lines were easy enough to discern with the spacing alone. Apologies if not.